# Passport.authenticate exporting -> passport.authenticate( some stuff ) (req, res, next)?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, passport-jwt

I don't understand why do I need `(req, res, next)` after the `passport.authenticate` function

Using this with express, I followed a tutorial, didn't explain this passage too well

PS: everything works fine, I just don't understand why that is needed

```
const passport = require('passport')

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('jwt', (err, user) => {
    if (err || !user || user.isAdmin !== true) {
      res.status(403).send({
        message: 'Request blocked, only administrators'
      })
    } else {
      req.user = user
      next()
    }
  })(req, res, next)
}
```

Function call as middleware

```
app.get('/admin', isAdmin, (req, res) => {
    res.send({
      message: 'You are an admin'
    })
  })
```

Passport strat config

```
passport.use(
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey: config.jwtSecret
  }, async (jwtPayload, done) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({
        where: {
          id: jwtPayload.id
        }
      })
      if (!user) {
        return done(new Error(), false)
      }
      return done(null, user)
    } catch (err) {
      return done(new Error(), false)
    }
  })
)
```

PSS: I had to make another file called isUser.js for users auth, how should I do if I want to put them both in the same file and require them as like

```
const Auth = require('./Auth')
Auth.isUser
Auth.isAdmin
```

I tried but I can't figure out how to do it with this type of function :(

Answer (score 1):

The `Express Route's` `next()` calls the next route handler or the middleware that is supposed to be handling the request after the request has finished been processed in the current method/middleware.

So as per you code (view my comments inside the code):

```
const passport = require('passport')

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('jwt', (err, user) => {
    if (err || !user || user.isAdmin !== true) {
      res.status(403).send({
        message: 'Request blocked, only administrators'
      })
    } else {
      req.user = user // THE user OBJECT IS ADDED TO THE req OBJECT SO THE NEXT ROUTE HANDLING METHOD/MIDDLEWARE MAY GET ACCESS TO THIS ADDED user OBJECT AND MAY USE IT
      next() // THIS CALL THE NEXT ROUTE METHOD/MIDDLEWARE
    }
  })(req, res, next)
}
```

So after the `next()` is executed here, the request is passed to be handled by an another middleware named `isAdmin` which would be checking if the current user is a normal user or an admin user based on the added user object retrieved from the request that was added by the previous middleware  as `req.user = user`

So if you want to avoid creating a separate file for `isAdmin` then you may something like:

```
const passport = require('passport')
// INCLUDE YOUR AUTH MIDDLEWARE FILE HERE
const isAdmin = require('./PATH/TO/isAdmin')

    module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
      passport.authenticate('jwt', (err, user) => {
        if (err || !user || user.isAdmin !== true) {
          res.status(403).send({
            message: 'Request blocked, only administrators'
          })
        } else {
          req.user = user
          // COMMENT OUT BELOW LINE
          // next()
          // IMPLEMENT THE AUTH LOGIC HERE, SOMETHING LIKE BELOW
          if (user.isAdmin()) {
          }
        }
      })(req, res, next)
    }
```

I hope this would help you